# Strange symbols when uploading a file with cyrillic names

Tags: php, laravel, encoding, dropzone.js, cyrillic

I am using Laravel and Dropzone.js. Everything's fine until I upload file with a cyrillic name. The file's name in the directory looks like - `РџСЂРёРµС‚Рё РїРѕ СЃРїРµС†РёР°Р»РЅРѕСЃС‚Рё_РѕРєРѕРЅС‡Р°С‚РµР»РЅРѕ-РЅРѕРІ_0` This is something with the encoding I guess. In `php.ini` I set `default_charset="UTF-8"` `internal_encoding = UTF-8` `input_encoding = UTF-8` But the problem is still unsolved. What could it be?

Comment: Did you check headers? `Content-Type` that is returned by your server ? Are you sure that you return are utf-8?

Comment: Did you check your file encoding? It may not be UTF-8.

Comment: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` well maybe the problem is not in the header

Comment: @E_p any other ideas?

Comment: @Alex And you 100% sure that files you return are UTF-8? Could be windows 1251... try output in different content types from PHP just as a check .  `text/html; charset=windows-1251` or `text/html; charset=iso-8859-1` see if one of them works. And check what is in your `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=?????">` tag of your html output

Comment: @E_p What do you mean by `files you return`?

Comment: @Alex My bad. Thought it was content going back problem. Did you check headers that are sent with your POST request to a server?

Comment: @E_p From `Response Headers` -> `Content-Type 
text/html; charset=UTF-8` and from `Request Headers` -> `Content-Type 
multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------322131509032319`

Comment: Not response but request. Posted my answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php
If you have it you can try:

```
$fileName = iconv("cp1251", "utf-8", $_FILES["upload"]["name"]);
// or
//  $fileName = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "utf-8", $_FILES["upload"]["name"]);


$baseDir = '/some/dir/';

move_uploaded_file(
    $_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"],
    $baseDir.$fileName
);
```

Comment: It's late at night in my country. I'm going to bed. Will check it to tomorrow. Thanks for your time

Comment: Hey, unfortuantely this doesn't work for me...the filename still looks awful

Comment: @Alex Try to swap `"cp1251", "utf-8"` -> `"utf-8", "cp1251"`. Did you try `cp1251` and `ISO-8859-1`

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm below is working:

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

```
if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    echo 'Error';
}
else {
    $baseDir = 'uploads/';
    $fn = iconv("utf-8", "cp1251", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $baseDir.$fn);
    echo 'Success';
}
```